# Which step in Android Build process removes the /res/raw directory?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

It seems that if I set debuggable = true in my build.gradle file and I build my project into an apk file, that if I unzip that apk, I can actually see the files in /res/raw.

However, if I have debuggable = false in build.gradle then when I unzip the apk file there is no longer a /res/raw directory (/res still exists).  I know the files are still part of the apk, because if I use apktool to decode the apk, then I see them in the /res/raw folder.

Is there a way to keep the /res/raw folder as part of the apk file hierarchy when debuggable is false?

EDIT:  this might be a strange request, but I am using a 3rd party library that looks at the apk, and needs to see the file at that location in the zip hierarchy.

Comment: Maybe `shrinkResources false`?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have tried that, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a particular step, then it's probably

```
 app:transformClassesAndDexWithShrinkResForRelease
```

It also shows a size of removed binary data - and it will be removed if it's not referenced in your code. If `shrinkResources false` doesn't work (although I'm not sure why, haha), you could try to specify explicitly which files should stay untouched per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources)

Comment: I don't see that task running at all, wether shrinkResources is true or false.   I already tried the information in the link you shared, but it doesn't help because the file is in the apk, but not in the location the third party is looking for it.  (I am working with the third party for a fix as well, but they are dragging their feet).